# How to add dots in the table of contents on chapter name

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I have a probleme with table of contents. The chapter's dots didn't work. How to fix it. This is my code

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin={2.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{placeins}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000



\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,beforeskip=2pt,entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}
%format daftar isi
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
[0pt]% <left>
{\bfseries}% <above-code>
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} 
\thecontentslabel \quad}%<numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75]{.}\bfseries}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-3em}{1.1\parskip}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}  
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
%format daftar lampiran
\newcommand\listappendixname{\centering \normalsize DAFTAR LAMPIRAN}
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{app}{chapter}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendices{
    \chapter*{\listappendixname}\@starttoc{app}}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[subsection]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{defn}[subsection]{Definisi}
\newtheorem{prop}[subsection]{Proposisi}
\newtheorem{exmp}[subsection]{Contoh}
\newtheorem{thm}[subsection]{Teorema}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\chapter{tes}
\chapter{a}
\section{b}
\subsection{c}

\end{document}
```

What is the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`tocloft`, `titletoc` and `tocbasic` do not work well together. If you just use `tocloft` then the following code:

```
\documentclass[...]{...}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
```

will produce dotted leaders in the ToC for chapters. See the manual (`> texdoc tocloft`) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `tocloft`, `titletoc` and `tocbasic` in the same document.

Suggestion using `tocbasic` (`tocloft`, `titletoc` and `\titlecontents` are removed):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin={2.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads also graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{hyperref}% <- load as last package
\allowdisplaybreaks

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,beforeskip=2pt,entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}
\newcommand\chapterprefixintoc[1]{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1~}% <- added

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-3em}{1.1\parskip}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}

%format daftar lampiran using package tocbasic
\DeclareNewTOC[
  owner=\jobname,
  type=appendix,types=appendices,
  listname={Daftar Lampiran}
]{app}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=\chaptertocdepth,
  indent=0pt,numwidth=0pt,dynnumwidth,
  entryformat=\textbf,
  linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  pagenumberformat=\textbf
]{tocline}{appendix}

\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
    \addxcontentsline{app}{appendix}{#1}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[subsection]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{defn}[subsection]{Definisi}
\newtheorem{prop}[subsection]{Proposisi}
\newtheorem{exmp}[subsection]{Contoh}
\newtheorem{thm}[subsection]{Teorema}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{tes}
\chapter{a}
\section{b}
\subsection{c}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have used `tocbasic` to define the List of Appendices, too.

[image]

Comment: Why the number of chapter BAB is disappear?

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya If added the missing argument to `\chapterprefixintoc`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `titletoc` package, and the preamble features the following code chunk:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
[0pt]% <left>
{\bfseries}% <above-code>
{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel \quad}%<numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\hfill\contentspage}
```

The `\hfill` directive in the final line of this chunk directs LaTeX to insert as much whitespace as it can between the chapter number and name and the associated page number. To switch from whitespace to dot leaders, I suggest you replace `\hfill` with

```
\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\bfseries
```

This sets the horizontal distance between dots to `0.75em`; feel free to modify this setting.

While you're at it, you may also want to change

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}\chaptername
```

to

```
\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}
```

With these changes in place, this is how the test table of contents should look like:

[image]

I can't help but remark that the layout of the table of contents looks rather haphazard. You currently load the `tocloft` package, but you don't actually use any of its facilities. I would like to recommend that you give some thought to improving the layout of the table of contents. In my opinion, using the macros of the `tocloft` package -- and dropping the `titletoc` package and its macros -- should let you achieve a better look.

Comment: How to make the dots bold for CHAPTER "BAB"? 

And how to make the dots is straight with before line?

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya - To make the dots **bold** (not something I would recommend...), remove the `\mdseries` directive. To align the dots of chapter-level headers with those of section-level headers, please post a new query. Speaking for myself, I find the entire layout of the ToC to be very poor. Aligning the dots across rows should be the least of your worries.

Comment: I have tried this code but it's still error, what is the solution? Please see my edited answer above

Comment: @amandadini -Why did you delete `\contentspage`?